# PhpMyAdmin and nginx configuration , get phpmyadmin after IP

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

What i'm trying to do is to access phpmyadmin from IP/phpmyadmin
I have edited the default conficuration file in the Site-available directory 
my configuration is :

```
server {
    location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
              location ^~ /phpmyadmin/ { 
            alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/; 
}
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }
}
```

But when I go to IP/phpmyadmin
it redirects me to the maini index file which we see the Welcome to nginx! message 
Any help would be great !

Answer (score 2):

I found out what was wrong! 
I just needed to add the symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/nginx/www
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you needed to add the `server_name` with your IP, and maybe also disable the default server, what you did is just tricking nginx.

Comment: `server_name localhost` will match `http://localhost/` but `xx.xx.xx.xx/phpmyadmin` will match `server_name xx.xx.xx.xx`, if you want it to match both then you can use both `server_name localhost xx.xx.xx.xx`